# Calendar in Vaadin 8

Tags: java, vaadin

Im trying to build an application with Vaadin. I have noticed that calendar component wasn't included in vaadin 8.
Is it possible somehow to use Calendar from Vaadin 7 in Vaadin 8 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Long version**

As per the [v8 release notes](https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.0/8.0.5/release-notes.html) (currently 8.0.5) there are a few [legacy components](https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.0/8.0.5/release-notes.html#legacycomponents) (including the calendar) that have not been ported to v8, but are included in a separate package. The [migration section](https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.0/8.0.5/release-notes.html#migrating) describes briefly what the compatibility dependencies contain:

> ## Migrating to Vaadin Framework 8.0
>
> Vaadin Framework 7 applications need some changes when migrating to
>   Vaadin Framework 8. In addition to updating dependencies, all
>   references to Framework 7 style data binding and components using it
>   need to be updated either to use new Framework 8 style data binding or
>   to use the compatibility versions in separate packages.
>
> **Vaadin Framework 7 compatible versions of the old data binding API and
>   components (with the exception of Form) are available in the package
>   com.vaadin.v7 in modules vaadin-compatibility-server,
>   vaadin-compatibility-shared etc. that can be used instead of
>   vaadin-server, vaadin-shared etc. The package
>   vaadin-compatibility-client-compiled contains the widgetset
>   com.vaadin.v7.Vaadin7WidgetSet which can be used instead of
>   DefaultWidgetSet**. Note that the widgetset compilation for
>   Vaadin7WidgetSet compilation requires at least 1G of memory. To ensure
>   this, add -Xmx1G to the
>   vaadin-maven-plugin configuration in your pom.xml file.
>
> All applications using either Reindeer, Runo, Chameleon or Base theme
>   must include the vaadin-compability-themes package.
>
> Some Vaadin Framework 7 add-ons do not work in version 8 - please
>   check the add-ons in Vaadin Directory for Framework version 8 support

Additionally, from the [migration](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/migration/migrating-to-vaadin8.html) section of the Vaadin docs regarding the packages:

> ## Updating Maven Dependencies
>
> For maven based projects including compatibility packages is simply a
>   matter of changing the artifactId of the desired non-compatibility
>   dependency to the compatibility variant. For example in the case of
>   changing the vaadin-server dependency from Framework version 7.7.6 to
>   8.0.0 would require changing
>
> ```xml
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
>   <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
>   <version>7.7.6</version>
> </dependency>
> ```
>
> to either
>
> ```xml
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
>   <artifactId>vaadin-compatibility-server</artifactId>
>   <version>8.0.0</version>
> </dependency>
> ```
>
> for including both compatibility features as well as non-compatibility
>   ones, or alternatively
>
> ```xml
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
>   <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
>   <version>8.0.0</version>
> </dependency>
> ```
>
> to only include Framework 8 features. The full list of compatibility
>   packages available for Framework 8 are the following:
>
> - vaadin-compatibility-server
> - vaadin-compatibility-client
> - vaadin-compatibility-client-compiled
> - vaadin-compatibility-shared
> - vaadin-compatibility-themes

... and the [widgetset](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/migration/migrating-to-vaadin8.html#widgetset-changes):

> ## Widgetset Changes
>
> When using compatibility packages in your project you need to changes
>   references from the default vaadin client side widgetset
>   **com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet** to the one containing the compatibility
>   packages **com.vaadin.v7.Vaadin7WidgetSet**, which is available in the
>   **vaadin-compatibility-client-compiled** maven dependency. Typically,
>   widgetset recompilation will handle this automatically for you, except
>   for the following two cases which should be handled manually:
>
> - Your project defines a **custom widgetset**, in which case you need to
>     make sure **Vaadin7WidgetSet is inherited**
> - An UI in your project defines its widgetset with the annotation
>     **`@Widgetset("com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet")`**, which should be changed to
>     **`@Widgetset("com.vaadin.v7.Vaadin7WidgetSet")`**
>
> The widgetset compilation for Vaadin7WidgetSet requires at least 1G of
>   memory. To ensure this, add -Xmx1G to the
>   vaadin-maven-plugin configuration in your pom.xml file.

---

**TL;DR version**

Probably you need to add the following 2 dependencies to your project to have access to the compatibility components and widget set:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-compatibility-server</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-compatibility-client-compiled</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

... change  from `com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet` to `com.vaadin.v7.Vaadin7WidgetSet` and recompile your widgetset.

Comment: When i'm trying to add those dependencies it writes that they cannot be found.

Comment: @Radek23445 sorry, I copy-pasted them from a pom which inherits a spring-boot parent that manages their versions as well. Can you try adding the `<version>8.0.5</version>` (or ${vaadin.verison} or whatever you're using) to the dependencies and retry?

Comment: Tried adding version and it is still same.

Comment: @Radek23445 It has to be something on your side because they're present in the central [repo for sure](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cvaadin-compatibility-server). Try to force a dependency update from the IDE: if using idea from the maven tool window press the refresh button (or enable maven auto-import); in eclipse right click the project from the explorer tool window and select maven -> update project; otherwise google :-)

Answer (score 0):

https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/vaadin-calendar mentions that it is not currently supported for vaadin 8.

So no, it's not yet possible